# how to get data out of .then function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

trying to read outside of a then/catch statment.  It works fine inside .then but doesn't work inside of react html

```
class DashboardPage extends Component {
...

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users/me', this.yourConfig)
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response.data.name)
    console.log(response.data.email)

  })
 ....


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
     <p>Welcome {this.response.data.name}</p>
     <p>Your email is {this.response.data.email}</p>
      this is your token {this.tokenCookie}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You wont be able to do that, you might be able to assign a `this` property inside the `then` function

Comment: Use the `state` of a React component. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: For other cases, see [_How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1218980)

Comment: `this.response` no where is response set to this. And you should not be using this, should be using state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save `response` to the state. Something like this should work:

```
class DashboardPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {response: null};
    }

...

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users/me', this.yourConfig)
    .then((response) => {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data.name)
      console.log(response.data.email)
      this.setState({ response });
    });
  }
.... 
  render() {
    if (this.state.response == null) {
      return (<div className="App"><p>Response not loaded</p></div>); // Whatever you want to render when there is no response yet
    } else {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Welcome {this.state.response.data.name}</p>
        <p>Your email is {this.state.response.data.email}</p>
        this is your token {this.tokenCookie}
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Note: I changed the function (`function (response)`) to the ES6 arrow function so `this` can be used. You can also set a variable like `var that = this` and change `this` inside `function (response)` to `that`.

Comment: Be careful, setting the state in an async callback may happen after the component was unmounted. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: I tried your way and now i am getting  TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Comment: My bad @ChrisAllen, I forgot to update render to test for that. If `response` is null, you have to render something else. I updated the code to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use response variable outside that function 
The best way around is use state 
 Example in doc -> https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

```
 componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: result.items
              });
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
            (error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
              });
            }
          )
      }
```

Comment: Be careful, setting the state in an async callback may happen after the component was unmounted. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html